# C++ map: Is it faster to create a temporary variable or access the value with the key each time

Tags: c++, dictionary, key-value

Which is faster:

```
(*connectionsById)[connection->nextConnectionId].reachable    = calculationId;
(*connectionsById)[connection->nextConnectionId].numBoardings = connection->numBoardings;
(*connectionsById)[connection->nextConnectionId].journeySteps = connection->journeySteps;
```

Or:

```
Connection& tmpConnection = (*connectionsById)[connection->nextConnectionId];
tmpConnection.reachable    = calculationId;
tmpConnection.numBoardings = connection->numBoardings;
tmpConnection.journeySteps = connection->journeySteps;
```

Does the compiler will figure it out anyway?

(I am a beginner on C++)

Comment: Have you considered a reference?

Comment: Measure it and find out!

Comment: These snippets don't do the same thing: 1 changes the values on the object inside the map, 2 only changes a temporary copy.

Comment: Did you compare the generated code (assembly) ?

Comment: You do realize that the second example does not change the data in the map, but only in the copy called `tmpConnection`? As @nwp said, you should use a reference. Then, I expect the second example to be faster, specially if the map is very large, because you only have to look for the data once. But, as @lightness-races-in-orbit said: Measure it!

Comment: Why are you (apparently) using pointers to the map?

Comment: I added the reference. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

These are not equal:

```
(*connectionsById)[connection->nextConnectionId].reachable    = calculationId;
(*connectionsById)[connection->nextConnectionId].numBoardings = connection->numBoardings;
(*connectionsById)[connection->nextConnectionId].journeySteps = connection->journeySteps;
```

This will dereference `connectionsById` 3 times and set it's member variables accordingly.

```
Connection tmpConnection = (*connectionsById)[connection->nextConnectionId];
tmpConnection.reachable    = calculationId;
tmpConnection.numBoardings = connection->numBoardings;
tmpConnection.journeySteps = connection->journeySteps;
```

This will create a new object `tmpConnection`, copied from whatever object `connectionsById` is pointing to. Then it will modify *the copy* and not the original object.

If you want modify the original object you should use a reference: (using `&`)

```
Connection& tmpConnection = (*connectionsById)[connection->nextConnectionId];
tmpConnection.reachable    = calculationId;
tmpConnection.numBoardings = connection->numBoardings;
tmpConnection.journeySteps = connection->journeySteps;
```

---

Now, asking the same question with the reworked code snippet, both are similar/equal under the hood and thus the performance difference will be minimal/none.

Comment: The compiler could still optimise the first example. Compilers are clever.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit *Obligatory Turbo C++ reference here.

Comment: *Obligatory giggle here.

Comment: OP is from Canada though.

Comment: Unless you _did_ measure it, and it was (grossly, unacceptably) slower, I'd go with the second version because (to me, at least) it's much clearer (simplifying the triplicated `(*connectionsById)[connection->nextConnectionId]` makes spotting the properties and what you're setting them to much easier).

Answer (score 1):

The second one will be faster, but `tmpConnection` needs to be a reference if you actually want to change the values in the map instead of just that copy.

If you did use a reference (`Connection& tmpConnection = ...`), I doubt that the compiler would be smart enough to make the first code as fast as the second.  The first code performs 3 searches by key in the map while the second on performs the search once and caches the result.  The compiler would have to assume a lot of things to make that kind of optimization.  (For instance, you can use a map with your own comparison function for ordering and searching for key equality.  There is nothing stopping you from changing how that function behaves between the different searches.  Therefore, the compiler cannot assume the searches will achieve the same results).

However, if the map is relatively small, this difference may be negligible and writing clearer code may be of more importance.

#### Edit:

Here is an exaggerated test that shows the difference:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <chrono>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int niter = 100000;
    int nsearch = 1000;

    map<int, size_t> m = {{0,0}, {1,0}, {2,0}, {3,0}, {4,0}, {5,0}, {6,0}, {7,0}, {8,0}, {9,0}};

    auto t1 = chrono::steady_clock::now();
    for(size_t iter=0; iter<niter; ++iter) {
        for(size_t i=0; i<m.size(); ++i) {
            for(int k=0; k<nsearch; ++k) {
                m[i] += k;
            }
        }
    }
    auto t2 = chrono::steady_clock::now();

    map<int, size_t> m2 = {{0,0}, {1,0}, {2,0}, {3,0}, {4,0}, {5,0}, {6,0}, {7,0}, {8,0}, {9,0}};

    auto t3 = chrono::steady_clock::now();
    for(size_t iter=0; iter<niter; ++iter) {
        for(size_t i=0; i<m.size(); ++i) {
            size_t& val = m2[i];
            for(int k=0; k<nsearch; ++k) {
                val += k;
            }
        }
    }
    auto t4 = chrono::steady_clock::now();


    cout << "time 1: " << chrono::duration_cast<chrono::milliseconds>(t2-t1).count() << " ms" << endl;
    cout << "time 2: " << chrono::duration_cast<chrono::milliseconds>(t4-t3).count() << " ms" << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Compiling this with `-O3` with clang, I get these results:

```
time 1: 2915 ms
time 2: 3 ms
```

Again, for most cases, it is probably negligible, but caching the key lookup can have a big effect in some cases.

Comment: I tried this and since I don't repeat that block a lot of times, it does not change the calculation time significantly. However, it is much more readable.

Answer (score 0):

It's very hard to say what an optimiser will do, so normally the rule is just to write the code for clarity. If you're in an inner loop, cacheing the structure may help, but you need to time it to be sure.